# How to view cloudwatch rule target log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I created a rule in `cloudwatch` and attached a SQS queue as its event target. From the metric view of the rule, I can see all the invocation on the sqs queue are failed. But how can I view the detailed log about the failure?

In the rule view of cloudwatch, there is an link `Monitoring    Show metrics for the rule`, when you click this link you will see the metrics relates to this rule, similar to below screenshot:

[image]

The `FailedInvocations` tells you about failed invocations. I see all my requests are failed.

Comment: do you mean a cloudwatch event rule? if so, which type (schedule or pattern)? And what do you mean the 'metric view of the rule'? Need more information before answering, sorry!

Comment: Added more information about this

Comment: I would have suggested cloudtrail but it seems that SendMessage API calls are not logged :( One more thing you could try setting up another target for the event, eg a Lambda function or SNS Topic, and seeing what information you get from that.

Comment: I already tried a lambda function which can receive the event so I don't know what wrong with the queue